# What is the commonly used phrase (if any) to convey the meaning of "detail-oriented analyst"?

Tags: word-requests

I found the phrase

> オブジェクト指向プログラミング

for "object oriented programming".

Does 詳細指向な分析者 sound natural for saying "detail-oriented analyst"?

Comment: What does mean “detail-oriented analyst”?

Comment: Roughly speaking, it means that an analyst who always analyze every single thing thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hear rarely 詳細指向な分析者.

If it means that an analyst who always analyze every single thing thoroughly, I think it is close to 細部まで徹底的に分析する分析者. And you can use the word like 追及する and こだわる instead of 分析する.

Comment: +1 for your effort, how about 几帳面で徹底的な分析者?

Comment: I think it is a little different, 几帳面 represents the character of the person.